# Prometheus scrape node terminate time

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics

I am trying to figure out how I can get prometheus to scrape the termination time, specifically the time a Node was terminated giving a UNIX timestamp, of a Node inside a kubernetes cluster. I am using kube state metrics for exporting node information however in the [docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/node-metrics.md) there isn't any mention of termination time, like there is with [pods](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/pod-metrics.md).

I am wondering if I need to scrape the kube_node_status_condition gauge metric, and just be aware when the status changes. However I'm not sure what status I would look for in that case.

Let me know if additional information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kube State metrics now offers this as an option out of the box: https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/issues/1889